# ¿Debe conjugarse el verbo como singular o plural si hay una acción pero multiples objetos?

Tags: conjugación, número-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

No estoy seguro si esta bien formulada la pregunta, pero...

Frecuentemente me veo en duda con oraciones como la siguiente:

> **Recuerda que `pueden` haber varios adverbios en la misma oración.**

Yo así lo redactaría ya que me refiero a "varios adverbios".

Algunas personas me indican como correcto, pero otros me corrigen con:

> **> Recuerda que `puede` haber varios adverbios en la misma oración.**

Me indican que es porque solo se enuncia **una** posibilidad en **una** oración.

Ambos me suenan correcto y me encuentro con este tipo de duda con cierta frecuencia, pero no se como llamar esta dificultad y nadie parece capaz de indicarme una clara norma o regla que lo aclare.

Si alguien me pudiera aclarar cual es la forma correcta de pensar en este tipo de casos; si este tipo de duda tiene un termino especifico y donde puedo encontrar información al respecto estaria muy agradecido.

De antemano, Gracias!

Comment: Puede porque haber es impersonal cuando señala existencia

Comment: La regla es que el verbo concuerda con el sujeto, no con los objetos. En tus oraciones, no hay sujeto, porque son impersonales, y en ese caso es como si fuera 3ª persona del **singular**, como apuntan en otras respuestas. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: sucede lo mismo con "puede que haya" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como indica guifa en los comentarios, **el verbo "haber" es impersonal cuando denota existencia**, y por eso decimos:

- En la oración <strike>han</strike>**hay** varios adverbios.
- En la oración <strike>habían</strike>**había** varios adverbios.
- En la oración <strike>hubieron</strike>**hubo** varios adverbios.
- En la oración <strike>han habido</strike>**ha habido** varios adverbios.
- En la oración <strike>pueden haber</strike>**puede haber** varios adverbios.
- En la oración <strike>deberían de haber</strike>**debería de haber** varios adverbios.

Como puedes observar, cuando acompañan a "haber" con este significado, los verbos auxiliares asumen el mismo rol impersonal que el verbo principal.

Lo mismo sucede con personas, animales o lo que sea: *En el concierto **hubo** muchas personas* (no *hubieron*), *En el hotel **puede haber** cucarachas* (no *pueden haber*), *En el último año **ha habido** varios terremotos* (no *han habido*).

Si se sustituye "haber" por otro verbo, o si su uso es solamente auxiliar, entonces sí que se emplean las formas personales:

- En la oración pueden encontrarse varios adverbios.
- En el concierto estuvieron muchas personas.
- En el hotel han encontrado cucarachas.
- Los pasajeros hubieron de salir por la puerta de emergencia.

Comment: Gracias por toda la ayuda y la tan clara explicación!